# Flip (or invert) text in Pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame, flip

I've just started to use PyGame and i'm trying to figure out how to flip text horizontally and / or vertically but, so far, no luck. Here's my code so far:

```
import pygame, sys, datetime, os
from pygame.locals import *
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dateoftime = (now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((768, 768), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
White=(255,255,255)
Black=(0,0,0)
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('pricedown', 100)
text = basicfont.render((dateoftime), True, White, Black)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

pygame.transform.flip(screen,True,False)

screen.fill(Black)
screen.blit(text, textrect)
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
clock.tick(50)
```

Another thing i wanted to do is centre the text but change the y value for it. For example, keep the x value as the centre (calculated from textrect) but change the y value to 200 or 600. Same for when i want to change the x value. Also, what parts do i need to change to show the current time, (H:M:S) that updates every second. I tried to change the amount in "clock.time(50)" but that doesn't cut it.

If there are any errors in this in general, corrections will be well appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip the text after you render it. First remove the `pygame.transform.flip(screen,True,False)` and then add a `text = pygame.transform.flip(text, True, False)` right after you render it:

```
import pygame, sys, datetime, os
from pygame.locals import *

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dateoftime = (now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((768, 768), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
White=(255,255,255)
Black=(0,0,0)
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('pricedown', 100)
text = basicfont.render((dateoftime), True, White, Black)
# ADDED!
text = pygame.transform.flip(text, True, False)  # Flip the text vertically.
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

#pygame.transform.flip(screen,True,False)  # Get rid of this.

screen.fill(Black)
screen.blit(text, textrect)
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
clock.tick(50)
```